# How to test a webpage for different aspect ratios

Tags: css, web-deployment

Is there a tool that can mimic different screen aspect ratio? for example 16.9, 3.2, 4.3. I need to see the look and feel of a webpage and fix the css.

What I want to test is how the different rules will work such as

```
@media screen and (aspect-ratio: n/m) {
```

...
}

thanks,
es

Comment: Would chrome's dev-tools not be sufficient? You can open the mobile emulator, switch to responsive, and set the resolution to anything you like.

Comment: that changes dpi and resolution and not the screen aspect ratio.

Comment: Yes, but you could choose a resolution within the aspect ratio you want to test on. Like 800 x 600 would be 4:3

Comment: sorry you are correct 100%

Comment: Welcome  :-) - I placed it in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome's dev-tools. You can open the mobile emulator, switch to responsive, and set the resolution to anything you like.

You could choose a resolution within the aspect ratio you want to test on. Like 800 x 600 would be 4:3